# How can I delete a collection or index on ElasticSearch?

Tags: .net, elasticsearch

How can I delete a collection or index on ElasticSearch? I am using .NET and the Elastic server is on localhost.

Comment: use DeleteByQuery

Comment: As per documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete an index by the below API request

```
curl -X DELETE "http://HOST:9200/{index_name}"
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use NEST

[NEST Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nest)

use "ElasticClient"

```
ElasticClient Client = new ElasticClient(connestionString);
IDeleteIndexResponse result = Client.DeleteIndex(IndexName);
if(result.IsValid)
{
//do some work
}
```